# how to create array on json format in option select

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Here i want to create array on json format , i did every thing but insteed of text field i want use option select , bit that i not able to make array of json format ,i spent more than 1 hour for this but i can not get solution

```js
function createJSON() {
   result = [];
    $("input[class=email]").each(function() {
  var email = $(this).val();
   var items = [];
   $('.Check1:checked').each(function(){
    items.push($(this).val()); 
    });
  $("input[class=mobile]").each(function() {
    var mobile = $(this).val();
  
    result.push({email: email,mobile: mobile, multiselect: items})
  });
    });
    console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
Email<input title="Title1" type="text" class="email" >
     <input title="Title2" type="text" class="mobile">

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Office Space"> Office Space        
 </li>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Apartment"> Apartment        
 </li>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Villament"> Villament        
 </li>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Individual House"> Individual House       
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Row House"> Row House
</div>


<input type="button" id="btn-submit" value="submit" onClick="createJSON()">
</form>
```

Comment: It is working my example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well, do you want something like this ?

Here I make an example using `select multiple.`

```js
function createJSON() {
   result = [];
   items=[];
   $('.Check1:checked').each(function(){
  items.push($(this).val()); 
   });

   //var mobile = $(this).val();
   result.push({select:$('select').val(), multiselect:items});
   
  console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
<select multiple="multiple">
  <option value="option1">1</option>
  <option value="option2">2</option>
  <option value="option3">3</option>
  <option value="option4">4</option>
</select>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Office Space"> Office Space        
 </li>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Apartment"> Apartment        
 </li>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Villament"> Villament        
 </li>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Individual House"> Individual House       
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Row House"> Row House
</div>


<input type="button" id="btn-submit" value="submit" onClick="createJSON()">
</form>
```